# Rails Devise & ActiveAdmin single model routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I am using both Devise and ActiveAdmin, and I have them sharing a single `users` table via an is_admin flag.  My routes file looks like this:

```
Site::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

That gives me these routes

```
                 Prefix Verb       URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET        /admin/login(.:format)         active_admin/devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST       /admin/login(.:format)         active_admin/devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE|GET /admin/logout(.:format)        active_admin/devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST       /admin/password(.:format)      active_admin/devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET        /admin/password/new(.:format)  active_admin/devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET        /admin/password/edit(.:format) active_admin/devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH      /admin/password(.:format)      active_admin/devise/passwords#update
                         PUT        /admin/password(.:format)      active_admin/devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET        /admin/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST       /admin(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET        /admin/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET        /admin/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH      /admin(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT        /admin(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE     /admin(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
```

I want the admin dashboard to be available from `/admin`, but I want the user administration section to be available from `/users`.  So `new_user_session` would be at `/users/login` instead of `/admin/login`.

Anyone accomplish this?

Comment: Have you already found a better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that you can do this by omitting ActiveAdmin from devise.  Instead of this:

```
Site::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

Do this:

```
Site::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Active Admin itself can be configured to live at `/`:

```
# config/initializers/active_admin.rb
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.default_namespace = false
  # ...
end
```

At the same time, individual pages can be configured to be in custom namespaces:

```
# app/admin/dashboard.rb
ActiveAdmin.register_page 'Dashboard', namespace: :admin do
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I suspect there's a simpler solution since this seems like a fairly common use case.